# Animating an Angular js button

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm using an angular js button, but i cant seem to use conventional css&js methods to put animations on it..i'm trying to implement an opacity animation on the button.
can anyone please help?

**HTML**

```
<span id="sign_btn">
   <md-button>Button</md-button>
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
#sign_btn{
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
display:none;
opacity:0;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#sign_btn").css('display', 'block');
$("#sign_btn").css('opacity', '1');
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you are trying to get to work. Putting it in something like a jsfiddle will also help

Comment: It can be done, with `transition` css property

Comment: If possible share your Jsfiddle code ..

Comment: How do you try to apply the opacity exactly?
Please post your code

Comment: you use transition, therefore, it should be trigger, like on hover event for instance.

Comment: it doesnt show the opacity transition..i need the change to be animated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out the solution..

```
$("#sign_btn").delay(0).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use animation instead of transition.

First, create a custom animation

```
    @-webkit-keyframes opanimation {
          0% {
            opacity:0;
          }
          100% {
            opacity:1;
          }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes opanimation {
          0% {
            opacity:0;
          }
          100% {
            opacity:1;
          }
    }
    @-o-keyframes opanimation {
          0% {
            opacity:0;
          }
          100% {
            opacity:1;
          }
    }
    @keyframes opanimation {
          0% {
            opacity:0;
          }
          100% {
            opacity:1;
          }
    }
```

Then apply it to you element

```
#sign_btn {
   animation: opanimation 5s; //you can modify the seconds here
}
```

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2up5y71k/

Comment: how can i trigger the animation with js?

Comment: This will be triggered automatically (check fiddle). 
on this animation, the element will animate from 0 to 1 opacity. You can modify it according to what you want.

Comment: You should also remove the JS code you've posted in order for this to work.

Comment: i need to trigger the animation on an event, so i need the js code

Comment: On what event you want to trigger it?

Comment: on an input's text changed even

Comment: what's the class/id of the input from which you want to trigger the even?

Answer (score 0):

Transitions only work for changes from one visible state to another. Your button is initially `display:none;` so the opacity change is not considered as a change in opacity from one state to another. Remove it (use other techniques like positioning, `z-index`, `translate` etc to achieve similar effect) and the transition should work.

Comment: @ShanzidS.Bidhan then it should be some other issue with your code. Please share a [mcve]